# Простой MessageBox hook. Рассчет относительного адреса

Tags: c++, winapi, ассемблер, hook

У меня есть пример использования hook'а для функции `MessageBox`. Этот пример является рабочим, однако есть непонимание расчета адреса функции, на которую потом будет совершен абсолютный переход.

```
relative_offset = (DWORD*)(dst - src);
```

В моем случае получаются следующие значения `97108c - 75c50ea5 = 8ad201e7`. Но почему из меньшего числа вычитается большее?

Программа при этом работает корректно. `DWORD` это `unsigned long`, то есть происходит переполнение.

Весь код программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iomanip>

#pragma comment(lib,"user32.lib")

typedef int (WINAPI* defTrampolineFunc)(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType);
LPVOID trampoline_address;

// The proxy function we will jump to after the hook has been installed
int __stdcall proxy_function(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType)
{
    std::cout << "----------intercepted call to MessageBoxA----------\n";
    std::cout << "Text: " << (LPCSTR)lpText << "\nCaption: " << (LPCSTR)lpCaption << "\n";

    // pass to the trampoline with altered arguments which will then return to MessageBoxA
    defTrampolineFunc trampoline = (defTrampolineFunc)trampoline_address;
    return trampoline(hWnd, "yeet", "yeet", uType);
}

void install_hook()
{
    HINSTANCE hinstLib;
    VOID* proxy_address = &proxy_function;
    DWORD* relative_offset;
    DWORD* hook_address;
    DWORD src;
    DWORD dst;
    CHAR patch[5] = { 0 };
    unsigned char saved_buffer[5]; // buffer to save the original bytes
    unsigned char saved_buffer2[10]; // buffer to save the original bytes
    FARPROC function_address = NULL;

    // 1. get memory address of the MessageBoxA function from user32.dll 
    hinstLib = LoadLibraryA("user32.dll");
    function_address = GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "MessageBoxA");

    // 2. save the first 5 bytes into saved_buffer
    ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), function_address, saved_buffer, 5, NULL);

    // 3. overwrite the first 5 bytes with a jump to proxy_function
    src = (DWORD)function_address + 5;
    dst = (DWORD)proxy_address;
    relative_offset = (DWORD*)(dst - src);
    std::cout << std::hex << dst << " - " << src << " = " << dst - src << std::endl;

    memcpy(patch, "\xE9", 1);
    memcpy(patch + 1, &relative_offset, 4);

    WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)function_address, patch, 5, NULL);

    //// 4. Build the trampoline
    trampoline_address = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 11, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    hook_address = (DWORD*)((DWORD)function_address + 5);
    memcpy((BYTE*)trampoline_address, &saved_buffer, 5);
    memcpy((BYTE*)trampoline_address + 5, "\x68", 1);
    memcpy((BYTE*)trampoline_address + 6, &hook_address, 4);
    memcpy((BYTE*)trampoline_address + 10, "\xC3", 1);
}

int main()
{
    // call without hook
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "hello", "hello", MB_OK);

    install_hook();

    // call with hook (arguments will be altered through the proxy function)
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "hello", "hello", MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Но почему из меньшего числа вычитается большее?

Ваш код - это хук API методом **"сплайсинга"** (есть ещё правка таблицы IAT). Суть его в том, чтобы в 5-байтный пролог оригинальной функции, вставить инструкцию перехода `JMP` с указателем на фиктивную функцию. Для этого приходится использовать не абсолютный адрес перехода, а относительный, т.к. среди 11-ти разнообразных опкодов `JMP` нет подходящего для этих целей.

Вот таблица из руководства Интела том(2) **"Instruction Set Reference"** где видно, что опкод `E9h` (который вы вставляете первым байтом) требует 32-битного относительного смещения "Relative", при чём этот вариант валидный как для х32, так и для х64:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Относительный адрес - это всегда число со-знаком. Старший/знаковый бит числа определяет направление перехода - если он сброшен (адрес меньше `80000000h`), то переход осуществляется вперёд от текущего значения `EIP/RIP`, если-же старший бит взведён, то соответственно переход назад. Думаю арифметика немного прояснит ситуацию..

На своей Win7-x64 я получаю адрес 32-битной MessageBox() = `0x7545FD1E`, а база моего кода с хуком API = `00400000h`. При этом фиктивная функция в нём лежит по адресу `0x00403000`, который я и должен прописать в начало MessageBox(). Поскольку переход будет осуществляться назад, адрес должен быть отрицательным, а потому вычисляем его как: `00403000-7545FD1E=8AFA32E2`. Теперь чтобы из этого значения получить реальный адрес перехода, нужно сделать инверсию NOT с инкрементом: `not 8AFA32E2=7505CD1D +1`. В результате, процессор перейдёт по адресу: `7545FD1E-7505CD1E=00403000`, что и требовалось доказать.

Кстати в вашем коде имеется ошибка! Дело в том, что исполняемые страницы памяти user32.dll где лежит `MessageBox()`, имеют атрибуты **"Execute/Read"**, т.е. защищены от записи. Поэтому сомневаюсь, что через `WriteProcessMemory()` можно записать в них адрес перехода на фиктивную функцию. Правильней было-бы сначала функцией `VirtualProtect()` добавить атрибут **"Write"**, а потом уже осуществлять сплайсинг. Вот аналогичный код на ассемблере FASM, и результат его работы:

```
format   pe console
include 'win32ax.inc'
entry    start
;//----------
.data
oldFlags    dd  0
;//----------
.code
proc   Trampoline hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType   ;//<---- фиктивная функция!
       cinvoke  printf,<10,' MessageBox() is hooked!',\
                        10,' The jump address must be relative, not absolute.',0>
        ret
endp

start:  ;//<--------- Точка входа ------------------------------------------------
;//---- Находим адрес MessageBox() в user32.dll
        invoke  GetModuleHandle,<'user32.dll',0>      ;// EAX = адрес либы в памяти (она уже загружена)
        invoke  GetProcAddress,eax,<'MessageBoxA',0>  ;// EAX = адрес функции в ней
        push    eax   ;//<---------- запомнить его в стеке
        
;//---- Снимаем защиту от записи в страницы user32.dll
        invoke  VirtualProtect,eax,5,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,oldFlags

;//---- Сплайсинг -------------
        pop     esi               ;// адрес MessageBox()
        mov     byte[esi],0xE9    ;// вставляем первым байтом инструкцию JMP rel32
        mov     eax,Trampoline    ;// адрес фиктивной функции (= 00403000h)
        sub     eax,esi           ;// 403000 - 7545FD1E = 8AFA32E2
        sub     eax,5             ;// коррекция..
        mov     dword[esi+1],eax  ;// вставляем DWORD после JMP

;//---- Проверим результат -------------
        invoke  MessageBox,0,<'Hello World!',0>,<'Caption',0>,0

       cinvoke  _getch
       cinvoke  exit,0
;//----------
section '.idata' import data readable
library  msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll',kernel32,'kernel32.dll',user32,'user32.dll'
include  'api\msvcrt.inc'
include  'api\kernel32.inc'
include  'api\user32.inc'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]